# Parallel writing from same DataFrame in Spark

Tags: apache-spark

Let's say I have a `DataFrame` in Spark and I need to write the results of it to two databases, where one stores the original data frame but the other stores a slightly modified version (e.g. drops some columns). Since both operations can take a few moments, is it possible/advisable to run these operations in parallel or will that cause problems because Spark is working on the same object in parallel?

Comment: Spark already parallelizes transformations/actions (thus writing) and also you can't parallelize 2 parallelized transformations/actions. That makes no sense for the scheduler.

Comment: You can use scala future

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.concurrent.Executors
import scala.concurrent._

implicit val ec = ExecutionContext.fromExecutor(Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10))

def write1(){
//your save statement for first dataframe
}


def write2(){
//your save statement for second dataframe
}

def writeAllTables() {
Future{ write1()}
Future{ write2()}
}
```

Comment: My question is whether it makes sense to do that (not how) or whether I would run into concurrency issues.

Answer (score 0):

Let me ask you, do you really need to do it? If you are not sure, then, you most probably don't.

So, lets assume below scenario similar to one you explained:

```
val df1 = spark.read.csv('someFile.csv') // Original Dataframe
val df2 = df1.withColumn("newColumn", concat(col("oldColumn"), lit(" is blah!"))) // Modified Dataframe, FYI, this df2 is a different object
df1.write('db_loc1') // Write to DB1, already parallelised & uses spark resources optimally
df2.write('db_loc2') // Write to DB2, already parallelised & uses spark resources optimally
```

1. Spark scheduler divides the first DataFrame `df1` into partitions and writes them in parallel in `db_loc1`.
2. It picks up the second DataFrame `df2` and again breaks it into partitions and writes these partitions in parallel in `db_loc2`.
3. By default, the degree of parallelisation per write is speculated in order to optimally use available cluster resources.
4. Small writes might not be repartitioned as mostly the write time is low and repartitioning will only increase overhead. In a extraordinary case where you have a lot of small writes, it might make a good case for trying to parallelise these writes. But, the best way to do so is to redesign your code to run one spark job per DataFrame instead of trying to parallelise `DataFrame.write()` call in same driver program.
5. Large writes will probably use all available resources in parallel during the single DataFrame write itself. Hence, if spark allowed issuing another write operation for a different DataFrame at the same time, it would only delay both operations as now they are racing with each other for resources. Not to mention, there may be some performance slowdown due to increased overhead because of sheer increase in number of tasks that spark now needs to manage and track.

Also, You can read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44305406/3122308) to and learn more about this