# SPARK Actions sequential

Tags: apache-spark

I am curious why a parallel engine such as SPARK serializes Actions standardly. E.g.:

```
df1.write.saveAsTable("TABLE_DF1")
df2.write.saveAsTable("TABLE_DF2")
```

occurs sequentially. I cannot find an official reason for this.

With say, PL/SQL, actions / db writes to the DB occur sequentially as per von Neumann cycle, but I would have thought that the DAG could compute that some aspects could occur in parallel, given enough resources.

Comment: Each actions is performed in parallel but differents actions are not. I suggest that you read the following https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44299920/how-to-write-rows-asynchronously-in-spark-streaming-application-to-speed-up-batc

Comment: Thx. Get that, but am asking exactly what the reason is for the other, other than creating a new Job. Seems SPARK is different, but ...

Comment: That's why I've updated with the link. Gerard explains very well what is happening

Comment: May be if I remember correctly that would not fit in with a DAG.

Comment: I don't understand your last sentence. What do you mean ?

Comment: I mean I get that the individual action must occur in parallel, else I would have to seek employment elsewhere... Or do you mean the DAG aspect?

Comment: thx for link. Seems to me that one can simulate what I mean, but whilst I saw Async for various options of Actions, I did not see for dfWrite API. I think this is relevant but never tried this what is mentioned by someone: "... Today you can already wrap the DataFrameWriter.save() call in a Future ..."  I guess I just expected this would be possible standardly. And I can create multiple Jobs -if the system can handle it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is how it works. Flooding subsystems with too many concurrent writes is generally an issue. Link eliasah provided should be consulted.