# Does spark write dataframes asynchronously

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have two spark dataframes df1 and df2.  I'm trying to write them out to two different file paths.  Can someone tell me, do the writes occur synchronously or asynchronously?  That is since they're two different dataframes writting to two different paths, will the writes occur at the same time, or do I have to wait until it finishes writing df1 out before it starts writing df2 out?

example code:

update added importing libraries:

```
import sys
from awsglue.transforms import *
from awsglue.utils import getResolvedOptions
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from awsglue.context import GlueContext
from awsglue.job import Job

glueContext = GlueContext(SparkContext.getOrCreate())

# updated 11/19/19 for error caused in error logging function
spark = glueContext.spark_session

from pyspark.sql import Window
from pyspark.sql.functions import col
from pyspark.sql.functions import first
from pyspark.sql.functions  import date_format
from pyspark.sql.functions import lit,StringType
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.sql.functions import substring, length, min,when,format_number,dayofmonth,hour,dayofyear,month,year,weekofyear,date_format,unix_timestamp
import time
import math

df1.write.mode("overwrite").parquet(filepath1)

df2.write.mode("overwrite").parquet(filepath2)
```

Comment: I don't think so they are running asynchronously. You have to wait for df1 to get completed and then it will start for df2. For more info, you can read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44299920/how-to-write-rows-asynchronously-in-spark-streaming-application-to-speed-up-batc

Comment: No, Spark writes rely on the Hadoop filesystem for parquet/orc/json/csv connectors, and it is blocking io. But spark itself also reserve 1 core for 1 task.

Answer (score -1):

If its on single thread it will write one at a time. You can use threding and share the spark Context.

Comment: thank you for getting back to me.  I updated my original post with the libraries I'm importing.  also I'm running this on aws as part of a glue job, if that helps.  Does this tell you if my code is single threaded?

Comment: Yes, its running on single thread. so first it will the df1 then df2.